# Cyrillic and PHPWord

Tags: php, unicode, encoding, phpword

The default encoding in my page is UTF-8. I have to write the document in Cyrillic. The whole application is in Latin script, so I can convert every single symbol from one to another, but I can't make PHPWord write Cyrillic letters. I made it write extended Latin (ŠĐĆČŽ), but I need it to write  Љ Њ Ш Ђ Ћ Џ Ц etc...

How can I make PHPWord write Cyrillic letters?

Comment: This doesnt really have a question anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this error with:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Does't matter that I had it defined in html meta tag, It works like this!

Comment: Where should it used for exported file?